# Where can i get complete-function-declaration offline help file for android..?

Tags: android

I am in search of an off-line help file for android. I used to work on Eclipse IDE. There i could not find any useful help topic for android.

I know android site itself providing a good tutorial. But can't come on-line all the time. Thats why i am searching for an off-line help file.

I googled to find any such files especially HTML help files. But i did not get any such thing.

Can anyone help me in finding that..?:)

Answer (score 1):

Install "Documentation for Android SDK" package using Android SDK Manager. It'll be downloaded to `SDK_PATH/docs`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me check that..:)

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the same Android doc that you can read in their website, it comes with the sdk you downloaded. The samples come with the sdk too if you checked the option during the sdk installation.